# Is there a ruby alternative to python templer?

Tags: python, ruby, zopeskel

In Python there is common to generate application skeletons with ZopeSkel. Recently ZopeSkel was refactored to define a new module named templer. In the process of creating skeletons templer not only copy dirs, also set values in template files, ask to the user and run processes.

I don't know something similar in Ruby. Is there a similar project?

Comment: generators for just Ruby, Ruby on Rails, or other framework?

Comment: generators for anything. The idea is to create a dir with templates and write some rules to make the project skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

The [Monk project](https://github.com/monkrb/monk) does just that. If you look around you'll find plenty of other people's skels to use too.

Answer (score 1):

For Rails there are a couple of "custom" generators:

- https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer
- https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer